# Wrapper method for mysqli_bind_param

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm writing a Database wrapper class and need something like:

```
public function bind($types, $params, ...) {
    $this->prep->bind_param($types, $params, ...);
}
```

How can I make the arguments dynamic, to have N-params?

I know of the function `func_get_args()` but doesn't help, I can fetch the arguments, but how to pass?

Comment: I think you're gonna have to fall back to [`call_user_func_array()`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)

Comment: Your problem is how to pass the arguments to your `bind` method or to `bind_param`?

Comment: @toro2k how to pass them to `bind_param`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, you could do it using `call_user_func_array()`:

```
public function bind() {
  $args=func_get_args();
  $method=array($this->prep,'bind_param');
  call_user_func_array($method,$args);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `call_user_func_array` should be what you need, something along the lines of the following:

```
public function bind () {
    $args = func_get_args();
    call_user_func_array(array($this->prep, "bind_param"), $args);
}
```

`call_user_func` and `call_user_func_array` can sometimes be a little slower than calling a method directly, unfortunately there isn't much you can do about this apart from hard code in the first few arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array, i advise you to use the classic way and keep some "core" arguments away from the array, than you can put optionnal ones in an array like so:

```
function function(Class $object, array $options = array()){

}
```

Comment: arrays can't be typecasted in PHP ?

Comment: yeah for sure, i mean by this, you can just use an array as an argument "container", you can put your N arguments in it.